# Node/Apollo/Sequelize onboxiously slow (>7 seconds)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I'm no expert in these things (I'm used to Laravel), but running one query in Apollo Server is taking ~7.2 seconds, for maybe 300 items total.

The entire resolver is below - as you can see there's essentially no logic aside from running a query. It's just humongously slow.

```
    getMenu: async (parent, {
        slug
    }, { models, me }) => {
        const user = await models.User.findByPk(me.id)

        const account = await models.Account.findByPk(user.accountId, {
            include: [{
                model: models.Venue,
                as: 'venues',
                include: getVenueIncludes(models)
            }],
            minifyAliases: true
        })

        return account.venues.find(venue => venue.slug === slug): null
    },
```

I realise this is rather vague, but does anyone happen to know where I'd look to try and improve this? I understand they're different, but in a Laravel app I can load 10 times that amount (with more nesting) in under a second...

Answer (score 2):

Aha!!

`separate: true` on your hasMany relationships. Good grief, cut request times from 7.2 seconds to 500ms.

Amazing.